# Code breaks when I don't output the variable; works when I do. WHUT?

Tags: c++

I don't really know what more to say about this.

I have never, ever seen this happen.  And it just boggles me what causes this.  I figured you guys might have seen this before and now what silly thing I am doing.

Notes about it:  'temp' is a variable the function is taking in.  It is a Binary Tree Node (BTN).  temp->d accesses the data.  ->l is left child, ->r is right child. ->p is parent

NOTE:  THIS IS HOMEWORK.  IT IS FOR A PRIORITY QUEUE.

NOTE2:  I have looked at similar questions.  All have suggested a timing error and the 'cout' 'slows' the code down.  What would cause this?  I can't think of any really 'costly' things I am doing.

```
  BTN<generic>* nTemp;
  cout << "Sdf\n";
  if(temp->r != NULL)
  {
    if(temp->l != NULL)
        {
          if(*(temp->r->d) > *(temp->l->d))
          {
            if(*(temp->r->d) > *(temp->d))
                {
                  cout << "ASDfs5: " << *(temp->d) << "\n";  //THIS IS WHAT KEEPS IT FROM BREAKING / SEGFAULTING
                  nTemp->d = temp->d; //THIS IS WHERE IT BREAKS (SEGFAULT)
                  cout << "ASDfs\n";
                  temp->d = temp->r->d;
                  cout << "ASDfs4\n";
                  temp->r->d = nTemp->d;
                            cout << "ASDfs3\n";
                  if(temp->r != NULL)
                  {
                    checkPopValues(temp->r);
                            cout << "ASDfs2\n";
                  }
                }
          }
          else
          {
            if(*(temp->l->d) > *(temp->d))
                {
                  nTemp->d = temp->d;
                  temp->d = temp->l->d;
                  temp->l->d = nTemp->d;
                  checkPopValues(temp->l);
                }
          }
        }
        else
        {
          if(*(temp->r->d) > *(temp->d))
          {
            nTemp->d = temp->d;
                temp->d = temp->r->d;
                temp->r->d = nTemp->d;
                checkPopValues(temp->r);
          }
        }
  }
  else
  {
    cout << "sdfs\n";
    if(temp->l != NULL)
        {
          if(*(temp->l->d) > *(temp->d))
      {
            nTemp->d = temp->d;
                temp->d = temp->l->d;
                temp->l->d = nTemp->d;
                checkPopValues(temp->l);
          }
        }
  }
}
```

Comment: How many threads are you spawning and what do you mean by 'breaks?' Saying that it 'breaks' isn't helpful, we need a specific error or explanation.

Comment: It SegFaults.  Sorry, too used to being able to ask questions of people who are familiar with the assignment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure nTemp is initialized. I bet it isn't. The cout causes something "benign" to be placed in nTemp.

Comment: I won't bet. I can see that it isn't initialized.

Comment: It worked.  I initially tried to initialize nTemp->d, but it got all mad.  But, it works now!

Answer (score 6):

You aren't assigning anything to `nTemp`. It's pointing to garbage.

When you access it on the line that breaks, undefined behavior occurs. If you're lucky, you should get an access violation/segfault. If you're not lucky, it will silently 'work' but probably give you wrong results.

You need to assign a pointer to an existing `BIN<Generic>` to it or create a new one.

Answer (score 0):

nTemp is not allocated any space so you are writing to random memory.